# How to get internet going in my current circumstances? ( using a USB cable, another linux laptop and a cellphone with cellular data )

Tags: wifi-hotspot

Here's what I want to do :

Get my Wifi USB dongle to work on my Desktop PC on which I installed Linux.
The Wifi USB dongle has drivers for "Linux 2 and 3"... Either way, it doesn't work right now.

Here's a list of what I have at disposal that could be useful :

- Desktop with Windows and working Wifi USB dongle driver on it
- Laptop with Linux and connected to Wifi
- Smartphone with unlimited cellular data plan
- A USB cable to connect my Smartphone to my Laptop or Desktop
- A USB Key

What can I do to get Wifi running on my Desktop PC?

EDIT: My Linux distro is Ubunt 18.04. My WIFI USB dongle is a SUMGOTT Wifi Adapter USB Wireless Dongle Dual Band

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to the U&L stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get information on how to best post to this site. To get to your question, [please edit your post to include additional context](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/501953/edit). What Linux distribution are you using and what model of USB WiFi adapter are you using? Thank you!

Comment: When it is plugged in what is the output of ls usb?

Comment: my mouse and keyboard, but nothing that rings the name of my usb dongle

Comment: please add the output of `lsusb` (with the dongle in) to your question -- do not assume that it will show the same name as on the box or label. Also, have you installed the `linux-firmware` and `linux-firmware-nonfree` packages? By all means, do not try to build the old crappy sources from the producer's webpage -- they're usually just perfunctorily dumped there, they're not supposed to be used in any way ;-)

Comment: added a pic. i do not know if that's installed. let me check and ill post the replay here

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while ago, with a different Wifi adapter. I solved this by temporarily going with an ethernet connection to the router in order to download the proper Wifi driver in Linux. But this doesn't seem to be an option for you, so it looks like your three best methods would be, ordered by my personal preference:

**a)** Download the (Linux!) driver **(*)** while having Windows booted, shove it onto an USB stick (That's what you meant by 'key', right?), then change into Linux, re-insert the stick and copy it off from there. Be sure to have your USB-Stick formatted in a way that both OSes can access it (FAT should be fine for that). Install the Wifi driver in Linux.

**b)** Download the (Linux!) driver **(*)** while having Windows booted, then re-boot into Linux and mount the windows HD partition into your Linux file tree. For more help on this, see, for example, [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions).
Copy the driver over to the native Linux environment, then install.

**c)** A 3rd, if somewhat similar, method would be to just use the cell phone to download the (Linux!) driver **(*)**. Assuming you've got an USB connection working in your Ubuntu, just connect the mobile phone to the Desktop via USB cable, copy the driver over and proceed like usual.

**(*)** A quick look-up confirmed the driver seems to be easy to find and to download. However, that quick look-up didn't show me the manufacturer's page, so I refrain from putting a link in here.

Comment: Did you find the driver on a blank webpage starting with the letter "r" ? If yes, I couldn't run the install.sh. I needed make so I downloaded the package to install it. But to install it I needed GCC. But to install GCC I needed gnome shell extensions. But to install gnome shell extensions I needed gnome shell extensions so I kinda gave up at that point

Comment: why yes, although it isn't a blank page for me. Googling some more for the manufacturer's page failed so far, though the search results suggest this SUMGOTT company is to be viewed with caution (regarding fake products).

Comment: by blank i mean the overall theme was white, but the page wasnt all white